# Is there any way to set a function for a word which is longer than (e.g.) 10 letters?

Tags: html, css, fittextjs

I have a div to which random words are distributed by lot. To display these words I use this script:

```
 <script src="jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#my_random_word").fitText(0.6);
    </script>
```

The problem is that when my word is longer than 10 letters is too wide for the screen and instead of resizing, it just overflows the screen's width.
CSS:

```
#parent_of_my_random_word {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#my_random_word {
    color: red;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
    }
```

Is there any way to specify another function for the words longer than 10 letters or what else can I do? Thanks.

Comment: I feel like you could solve this with CSS rather than JS. Perhaps `overflow: hidden` and a `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, though I can't be sure with what's in the question. If you have to do it in JS, just stick an `if` in checking length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to cut the word off and prevent overflow.

Or you can handle it with JS:

```
var myWord = $("#my_random_word").text();

if (myWord.length >= 10) {
   // ... handle it
} else {
   myWord.fitText(0.6);
}
```

To check for multiple words you can use regex. The following looks for a simple pattern of `word-space-word`

```
var pattern = /\w\s+\w/;

'word'.match(pattern); // null
'multiple words'.match(pattern); // match found
```

Comment: I have one more question. Is there any way to specify between one word and more words. I mean #my_random_word can have two or three words as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use css `word-break: break-all;` to break the word.

```css
.content {
  word-break: break-all;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">veeeerrrrryyyyylonnnng worrrdd</div>
```